# RavenDB dynamic query not giving correct results

Tags: ravendb

I have a set of documents with field name "DocumentType". This field holds different values like "Email","Text file","Contact" & etc..
By using RavenDb dynamic query, when I searched for DocumentType:email, the results are coming fine. If I do some edit to the existing document DocumentType - ex: changing the DocumentType value from Email to Memo & then searching for the documents with document type "Memo"
i.e Query  - DocumentType: memo, the results pane showing "There are no results for this query". Please let me know the issue with my query.

Thanks,
Dilip Kumar

Answer (score 0):

Did you store your edited document before saving it. It happened to me also but I realized I forgot to store the edited document even though I loaded it from the database. For example:

```
var teacher12 = session.Load<Teacher>("teachers/12");
//changes to teacher12
....
session.Store(teacher12);
session.SaveChanges();
```